# Can you pass a series of parameters to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I have made with a year parameter. But I want to know if there is a way that I can pass more that 1 year at a time to the stored procedure?

So instead of having to run it once for 2012, then again for 2013 etc., is there a way to set it up that I can pass a range or series of parameters an have it run for each one?

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: If your DBMS supports the `ARRAY` data type, you can use that as your input parameter to pass in multiple year values

Comment: If I want to pass multiple records for insert I typically use XML documents to pass into my stored procedure.

Comment: You may be asking the wrong question. How do you run the stored procedure for a single year? Take THAT process and automate the execution of the procedure for a series of years. For example, if you are executing a very simple anonymous block to call the procedure with input 2012, write a loop in the anonymous procedure to call it for 2012, then 2013, then 2014, etc.

Comment: @mathguy would you be able to give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is for PL/SQL (the Oracle procedural language). If your db is different, the syntax may be different, but the idea should be the same.

Suppose your procedure looks like this:

```
create or replace procedure do_something( y in number )
as
begin
  if y = trunc(y) and y between 2000 and 2020
  then
      dbms_output.put_line('Your input was: ' || to_char(y, '9999'));
  else
      dbms_output.put_line('You did not input a year between 2000 and 2020');
  end if;
end;
/

Procedure DO_SOMETHING compiled
```

And you normally call it like this. Since the procedure outputs to the output buffer, first make sure that will be directed to the screen, with `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`.

```
set serveroutput on

begin
  do_something(2018);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Your input was:  2018
```

Now suppose you need to run the procedure for 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021 - and you want to automate it. Do so by writing a loop in the anonymous procedure which calls your `do_something` procedure:

```
begin
  for yr in 2018..2021
  loop
    do_something(yr);
  end loop;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Your input was:  2018
Your input was:  2019
Your input was:  2020
You did not input a year between 2000 and 2020
```

For the more general case, where you need to give a list of inputs (in some arbitrary order), you can create a table of values and loop over it.

```
declare
  type num_tbl_type is table of number;
  inputs num_tbl_type := num_tbl_type(2013, 2022, 2016);
begin
  for idx in 1..inputs.count
  loop
    do_something(inputs(idx));
  end loop;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Your input was:  2013
You did not input a year between 2000 and 2020
Your input was:  2016
```

Comment: thank you for this, pretty sure this is exactly what I needed, now just to wrap my head around it. this is the SP I am trying to automate with the loop  [code]create procedure [dbo].[updeate_las_program_health]
year int 
as
update LAS_Program_Health set Joins = (select count([ID])
from [dbo].[EPT_Program_Memberships]
where [EPT_Program_Memberships].[Joined Year] = year), [Cancels] = (select count([ID])
from [dbo].[EPT_Program_Memberships]
where [EPT_Program_Memberships].[Cancelled Year] = year)
where LAS_Program_Health.Program = 'EPT' and Year = year 
GO[code]

Comment: thanks again see above the SP I am trying to work with

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no easy way to pass an array of values to a stored proc. But you have several options to work around that most notably xml parameters. I personally like to pass a comma delimited list of values and parse it myself in the stored proc.

Comment: Have you heard of a `table valued parameter`?